# g++ error with standard library (limits.h)

Tags: c++, g++, std, g++4.8, g++-4.7

I was trying to install OpenBR from http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/installation.html and I am getting an error with the standard c library.

```
/home/vinaychandra/OpenBR/openbr/openbr/janus.cpp: In function ‘janus_error janus_verify(janus_flat_template, size_t, janus_flat_template, size_t, double*)’:
/home/vinaychandra/OpenBR/openbr/openbr/janus.cpp:123:40: error: ‘lowest’ is not a member of ‘std::numeric_limits<double>’
     else                 *similarity = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
                                        ^
make[2]: *** [openbr/CMakeFiles/openbr.dir/janus.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [openbr/CMakeFiles/openbr.dir/all] Error 2
```

All I know is that numeric_limits is the standard c++ library. And such an error should not exist. Please explain why this problem is occurring.

My g++ version is 4.9.0. I also tried it with 4.8 and 4.7 versions.

Comment: I actually ran a make command in the folder. Where do you want me to try the command?

Comment: You need to add flags to the [`cmake`](http://www.cmake.org/) command you use to create the makefiles, to tell [`cmake`](http://www.cmake.org/) to add `-std=c++11` to the compiler flags. I suggest you read the [CMAKE documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenBR has been reporting problems when you are trying to use the latest version of Ubuntu. This might be because of g++ version and some other libraries. Please revert to 13.04 to use OpenBR to its full extent

Comment: Yes, This worked. I tried with other options but none of them quite worked out